# How to send image from Android to FTP

Tags: android, image, upload, ftp

i don't know if the following is correct to the connection, I have a IOException.

sb=[ftp://IDUSER:password@ftp.fercode.com/manolo;type=i](ftp://IDUSER%3apassword@ftp.fercode.com/manolo;type=i)

```
URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
urlc.getOutputStream();// this line throws a IOException
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FTP client like Apache to properly upload and downland files.

Take look here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html